# MySQL Show results where not all conditions are met

Tags: mysql

I have three tables

Table A (orders)

```
 order_number     order_id
     9999            123
```

Table B (order_items)

```
order_id    product_id    price
   123         111          10
   123         112          11
   123         113          12
   123         114          13
```

and Table C (product_customfields)

```
product_id    customfield_id      customfield_value
  111              10                   A
  112              10                   A
  113              10                   B
  113              9                   xyz
```

As a result I would like to get the product_id the price and in case a product has the customfield_id = 10 also the customfield_value

So in this case as a result I expect:

```
product_id   price    customfield_value
    111       10            A
    112       11            A
    113       12            B
    114       13          (empty)
```

In general my query looks like the following:

```
select B.product_id, B.price, C.customfield_value from orders A 
left join order_items B on A.order_id=B.order_id 
left join product_customfields C on B.product_id=C.product_id where A.order_number=9999 and C.customfield_id = 10
```

Of course the result will not show the product_id 114 because it has no customfield_id assigned in the database table with a value of "10"

Nevertheless could someone point me in the right direction how to build the query in a way to also show all products of the orders also if they are not assigned to a condition in the table.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Does

```
select B.product_id, B.price, C.customfield_value from orders A 
left join order_items B on A.order_id=B.order_id 
left join product_customfields C on B.product_id=C.product_id 
where A.order_number=9999 and (C.customfield_id = 10 or C.customfield_id IS NULL)
```

solves your issue?

Comment: Unfortunately not. It does still not return the product which has no customfield_id=10 assigned. Also product 114 could be assigned to a customfield_id = 9 in the future. The main thing is that it is not assigned to customfield:id=10 however I would still get it as a result.

Answer (score 0):

You need a left outer join on the **product_custom_fields** like this

```sql
select B.product_id, B.price, C.customfield_value 
from orders A 
left join order_items B 
     on A.order_id=B.order_id 
left outer join product_customfields C 
     on B.product_id=C.product_id 
where A.order_number=9999 and 
      (C.customfield_id = 10 or C.customfield_id IS NULL)
```